# How to dynamically change sidemenu when loggedIn?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a sideMenu in my ionic project. I have a menu login. In my menu controller I have:

```
if (logged) {
    $scope.loginText = 'Login';
}else{
    $scope.loginText = 'Logout';
}
```

In my menu I simply add a {{loginText}} in the correct menu.

Then I do the login in another controller. When the user log in, I have to refresh the page to change the text. How can I change the text without need to refresh?

Comment: where does the logger variable reside?? i mean is the variable a scope variable??

Comment: can you tell me what is the relevance of the logged variable?? are you changing it after logging in.. where is it set?

Comment: the logged variable is set to true or false each time needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the variable logged change is not detected on login. Since it is in different controller the change has to be manually send. this can be achieved by using $rootScope to send messages through different controller which are under the same parent controller. hence a message or an event has to be send. the below code will help.

in login controller after logged in.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('isLOggedIn', true);
```

in menu controller

```
$scope.$on('isLOggedIn', function (event, data) {
  if (data) {
    $scope.loginText = 'Login';
  }else{
    $scope.loginText = 'Logout';
  }
});
```

remember to inject $rootScope in login controller.